# Lint error when using adaptive launcher icon

Tags: android, lint, adaptive-icon

Since i'm using an adaptive launcher icon for my app, i get a lint error when building my app.

> **Error: Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in anydpi-v26 [ManifestResource]**
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"se
>   src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:2: This value will not be used
>   Explanation for issues of type "ManifestResource": Elements in the manifest can reference resources, but those resources cannot vary across configurations (except as a special case, by version, and except for a few specific package attributes such as the application title and icon.)

I don't know where the "se" in "android:roundIcon='@mipmap/ic_launcher_round'se" is coming from and if this is problem.

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.3 (Also tried this with early version 3.1.2)

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong or where the problem is?

**Update**
My ic_launcher_round.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

I have a debug and a release configuration to use different background color for release and debug builds.

Comment: Did you check the contents of the file `ic_launcher_round.xml`?

Comment: I updated my question with the code of my `ic_launcher_round.xml`